# How to add reference for "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to integrate Microsoft Word with C#. But when i am trying to add Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" I couldn't find this in the reference list:

What am I missing? I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012.

Please help...

Comment: you *probabbly* need to have MS office installed on your machine

Comment: Do you have the office Primary Interop Assemblies (PIAs) installed?  Its available, I think, through the add/remove programs on MS Office.

Comment: I have already installed MS Office on my machine

Answer (score 5):

To add a reference to a primary interop assembly:

1. Open your Visual Studio Tools for Office project and select the project name in Solution Explorer.
2. On the Project menu, click Add Reference.
3. On the .NET tab, select the primary interop assembly you want in the Component Name list. For more information about the available Microsoft Office primary interop assemblies, see [Office primary interop assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
4. Click OK.

The assembly name appears in the References folder of Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install MS office to your computer.

Or download the Primary Interop Assemblies from here.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Then add it to your project reference.

Comment: downloading the Primary Interop Assemblies not working in my case

Comment: @sohaiby do you MS office installed on your machine?

Comment: nope. I am looking for a solution that doesn't include installing MS Office

Comment: @sohaiby There is no solution like that. In order to use the libraries you must have Office installed.